# Oracle ADF - Jdeveloper use shortdesc in input from the value of another attribute of the View object

Tags: input, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an input and I want to populate the shortDesc atttribute with the value of another attribute of the View Object, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bindings on the page, create an attributeValues binding to the View Object. Then in shortDesc property, it will be:

```
shortDesc="#{bindings.nameOfAttributeValuesBinding.inputValue}"
```

As the View Object goes to a given row, the attributeValues binding updates with the value. You may need to put a partial trigger on the component so it will update when a UI action takes place depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much, this work fine, on the other hand I also tried the following solution:

Comment: shortDesc="#{row.nameOfAttriibute}"

Comment: @csuazo hmmm, that approach should work I would think. Without more details hard to say.